# Hard coded value based on the filed name in jolt spec

Tags: jolt

I am using jolt to convert one json to another json but I am not getting correct output json for given input json

Input :

```
{  
  "user":{  
        "homePhone":"12345678901",
        "mobilePhone":"12346750983",
        "email":"test@example.com"
   }
}
```

Expected Json :

```
{  
   "contact":[  
    {  
      "class":"PhoneClass",
      "phoneNumber":"12345678901",
      "mobile":false,
      "preferred":false
   },
   {  
      "class":"PhoneClass",
      "phoneNumber":"12346750983",
      "mobile":true,
      "preferred":true
   },
   {  
      "class":"EmailClass",
      "email":"test@example.com"
   }
]
}
```

In output json there are some extra field also I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

How much of this is dynamic? If for your example you know you'll have those three input fields and want three output objects, this spec should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user": {
        "homePhone": "contact[0].phoneNumber",
        "mobilePhone": "contact[1].phoneNumber",
        "email": "contact[2].email"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "contact[]": {
        "0": {
          "class": "PhoneClass",
          "mobile": false,
          "preferred": false
        },
        "1": {
          "class": "PhoneClass",
          "mobile": true,
          "preferred": true
        },
        "2": {
          "class": "EmailClass"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you mattyb for your response and it is working fine but what about phoneNumber and email property which I need into output json, How I can add this i specs.

Comment: Where do you want to add them?

Comment: If you see Expected Json in my question, I want add them into contact array.

Comment: Using your input JSON and my spec, I get your Expected JSON out (although the fields are out of order). What are you getting?

Comment: I am getting {

  `"contact" : [ {
    "class" : "PhoneClass",
    "mobile" : false,
    "preferred" : false
  }, {
    "preferred" : true,
    "class" : "PhoneClass",
    "mobile" : true
  }, {
    "class" : "EmailClass"
  } ]
}`

this output.

Comment: Are you using a Chain spec with both the Shift and Default specs inside (as they are above), or are you just applying the Default spec?